# Using tflite on Android Studio for big images

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow

I've just reviewed the tflite version of tensorflow for poets 2 and, using the provided sample app, sort of reversed engineered the image clasification process to add it's functionality to my app. However, I find that when trying to clasify an image, if it's resolution is anywhere above 224px wide or high, an "indexoutofbounds" error will be issued.

I'm capturing the image from the phone camera, storing it locally, reading it's contents to a bitmap variable and then using the classifyFrame function from the ImageClassifier (from the app provided by Google in the tutorial) to obtain the results. Only works when I resize the Bitmap data to 224x224.

I tried changing the DIM_IMG_SIZE_X and DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y variables to higher dimensions in the ImageClassifier class but it didn't work. Also tried to up the allocated memory (4 * DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);) in the ImageClassifier initializer to 8x and 16x, but this also issued an error, saying that the size should be X when it's actually Y.

Is there another setting I should be changing for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you face the same problem with me, because it has define the input shape in .tflite file to 224x224, so you should rebuild a new .tflite file with new img size. For example, mobilenet:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \
  --input_file=$(pwd)/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/frozen_graph.pb \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --output_file=/tmp/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_type=FLOAT \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1 \
  --input_shapes=1,300,300,3
```